# Ckeditor converting superscript to square brackets when pasting from Word

Tags: ms-word, formatting, superscript

If I have a Word document with footnotes in it, they are referenced by a  superscript number in the body of the document. If I copy/paste my content into ckeditor, from LibreOffice, it preserves my superscript; however, if I copy/paste from Word, the superscript is converted to square brackets.

How do I preserve the superscript when pasting from Word?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Your issue is at the end-user level and should be posted in a forum like Super User or Microsoft Answers. Most likely, however, it has to do with the character set Word uses to mark the superscript as a footnote. It's not *just* a superscript - it has special, for us invisible, markings to identify it as a footnote within the Word environment. That's how, for example, you can click on it to jump to the footnote; or how it knows to update if you insert additional footnotes ahead of it.

Comment: I thought it could be either. I have a custom plugin that I use, and in it I place and an all config tweaks. For instance, CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false; to remove auto paragraphing. I though there may be an end-user solution to this problem, or a programmatic/configuration solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways this can be done. The one would be to edit the WordOpenXML. The other is to use Word's Find/Replace functionality. The last is much simpler to implement using VBA, since VBA has no internal tools for working with XML.

You'd need to run this macro before copying the content. Assuming the document should remain unaltered afterwards, I've included code to bundle the macro's action's in a single Undo entry, and then that Undo is executed at the end of the code.

In Word the term ^f can be used with Find to locate a footnote.

The code searches this term in a loop and replaces the found term with the footnote's index number. This removes the footnote marking that's tripping you up. The footnote style is then applied to retain the superscript formatting. Note that the loop runs from the end of the document to the start in order to retain the footnote numbers (otherwise they'd all be "1").

```
Sub ReplaceFootmarkWithSuperscriptNumber()
    Dim rngFind As word.Range
    Dim findTerm As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim lFootnoteNum As Long

    findTerm = "^f"
    Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.content
    Application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord

    With rngFind.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = findTerm
        .Forward = False
        Do
        bFound = .Execute
        If bFound Then
            lFootnoteNum = rngFind.Footnotes(1).index
            rngFind.Text = CStr(lFootnoteNum)
            'rngFind.Select
            rngFind.Style = ActiveDocument.styles(wdStyleFootnoteReference)
            rngFind.Start = ActiveDocument.content.Start
        End If
        Loop While bFound
    End With
    Application.UndoRecord.EndCustomRecord
    ActiveDocument.Undo
End Sub
```